# VIM not highlighting PHP files, highlights others

Tags: php, vim, syntax-highlighting, ubuntu-11.04

VIM is unable to highlight PHP files or indent it (using '=').
It is working fine for other file types (.html, .c, .java etc.)

I tried manually setting filetype/syntax without any results.

What should I do?

OS: Ubuntu 11.04
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Oct  6 2011 10:34:41)
Included patches: 1-154

Should I give more information?

PS: php.vim file is present in syntax folder.

Answer (score 10):

The default syntax plugin for PHP requires to include `<?php` at the beginning of the file to highlight anything.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what would cause this issue but try adding below to .vimrc

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.php set filetype=php
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using following vimrc lines:

```
filetype plugin on
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.endfile set filetype=endfile
filetype plugin indent on
```

The part with endlife helps for css, html and php files for example and for javascript I added:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile jquery.*.js set ft=javascript syntax=jquery
```

I hope that will help you.

Comment: Can you please show us your vimrc file? Another question would be to trigger syntax on. Maybe it is disabled for php by default whatsoever. You said that you have <?php at the beginning. No offense, but do you have ?> at the end as well?

Comment: Here is the link to my .vimrc file http://pastebin.com/caJfK8Dr

I tried both, with and without ?>. And it should not make any difference

Comment: Hi, i tried your vimrc file and the highlighting works fine. Only your tab ist awkward, but maybe you want it that way. I don't have your colorscheme so I haven't tested it. Maybe it is broken?

Comment: Thanks... I will change colorscheme and check. And i know tab is awkward :(. I have to fix it... didn't get time :P.